# Typeof of a javascript function is defined before the function is declared?

Tags: javascript, parsing, function, declaration, typeof

Could somebody please explain or link to a resource that will tell me why :

```
<script type=" type="text/javascript">

    if(typeof window.myfunc == "function"){
        alert("Why does myfunc already exist ?");
    }

    function myfunc(){

    }
</script>
```

will pop up an alert while the myfunc function has not been defined yet ?

I think I found an issue in Chrome, Safari and IE (not FF) which is linked to this behavior. It keeps me from extending the prototype of a function when the js file that contains the function is included more than once in a web page. I'd like to know more about this before calling it a bug and reporting it.

Thank you !

Comment: When you define your function as `var myfunc = function() {}` you will see the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Named function declarations, including the function body, get hoisted to the
top of the scope in JavaScript. I'd recommend reading [this article about
JavaScript scoping and
hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting).

If you did something like this, where you assigned the function to a named
variable, only the variable declaration would be hoisted, but it wouldn't have
a value until the assignment actually took place:

```
if (typeof myFunc == 'function') {
    // will not be reached
}

var myFunc = function() { ... }
```

The above effectively gets treated as:

```
var myFunc; // myFunc is undefined

if (typeof myFunc == 'function') {
    // will not be reached
}

myFunc = function() { ... }
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation Wyatt. I never realized thefunc

Comment: Thank you for the explanation Wyatt. I never realized the func = function(){ } syntax actually made a difference. This solved my case ! Because I run a webservice and when my javascript file is included twice, my function is hoisted twice too. The problem is, objects created with the function (like obj = new myfunc()) **before** the function is hoisted the second time are not affected by changes on the prototype of the function which have happened **after** the function has been re-hoisted. Hard to explain, but hopefully you'll get what I mean. Thanks anyway for the hint on the syntax !

Answer (score 1):

One word: *hoisting*

A quote from JavaScript Garden:

"The above function gets hoisted before the execution of the program starts; thus, **it is available everywhere in the scope it was defined in, even if called before the actual definition in the source**."

More info here: http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.general